# RSpec fails when comparing empty ActiveRecord::Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

I am testing my controller and I did something like this:

```
bar = SuperDuper.calculate(resource)
expect(assigns(:foo)).to eq(bar)
```

I got this as a result

```
expected: #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
     got: #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>

(compared using ==)
```

Why does RSpec see this as failure?

As you can see I use `eq` which ignores objects identity, not `equal` which compares object identity.

Comment: perhaps rspec is asserting equality of objects by links. So you have 2 identical objects but they are pointing to different areas in memory. Consider comparing by value instead of just object comparing

Comment: @tmn4jq Here I am using `eq` which compares values, not using `equal` which compares object identity

Comment: Debug with `expect(assigns(:foo).to_a).to eq(bar.to_a)` or `expect(assigns(:foo).to_sql).to eq(bar.to_sql)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but you `eq` means `==`. Proof: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-0/docs/matchers/equality-matchers

Also note this: 
`a.eql?(b) # object equivalence - a and b have the same value`

It's from here: [Rspec `eq` vs `eql` in `expect` tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32926817/rspec-eq-vs-eql-in-expect-tests)

So, I believe you should try the `eql` matcher.

Comment: I got this:

`expected: #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>` `got: #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>` `(compared using eql?)`

Comment: @MohamedAnwer consider reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26482564/rspec-eq-matcher-returns-failure-when-two-things-are-equal, https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/matchers/activerecord-relation-match-array and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26935630/rspec-matchers-when-working-with-activerecordrelation